# How to build one project with/without google ads?

Tags: android, project, ads

I have an android project that includes Ads and want to distribute it also as an ad-free payable 1$ app.

How could I build the same project in 2 ways?

- Build 1: Project with Ads
- Build 2: Project without Ads

Any advise?

Comment: if you change the package name you can have a free and a paid version, the user can have both the free and the paid

Comment: You could just add in-app purchases to turn off the ads, this way you just have to maintain one application and one application listing in the Play Store that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMOP, you should add `Ads` programmatically (banner, fullscreen ads...), then you can have a `constant variable` such as: `isAdFree` which is condition to add `Ads` or not. when you want to build free ads project, you just change your `constant`value.